# how to deal with a function pointer problem?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, c++17

i'm implementing a normal function pointer.

so this is the function that i want to call:

> 

```
  WndDyn* Punkt2d::pEditPunkt(WndInfo& wi, Int32 AnzSichtChar, Bool WithUnit, 
  const DecimalsConf& DecConf)
  {
     WynDyn_callback Dyncallback;
     Dyncallback.AnzSichtChar = AnzSichtChar;
     Dyncallback.WithUnit = WithUnit;
     Dyncallback.DecConf = DecConf;

     return &(DlgZeile(wi)
            + pEditAll(Dyncallback, &pEditFeldX)//pEditFeldX(AnzSichtChar, WithUnit, 
              DecConf)
            + FntXUnit(2)
            + pEditFeldY(AnzSichtChar, WithUnit, DecConf)
             );
   }
```

After defining the function that needs to be called i defined my callee as follow:

```
WndDyn*   pEditAll(WynDyn_callback& Dyncallback, WndDyn* (func_Call) 
      (WynDyn_callback)) {
        return  func_Call(Dyncallback);
    }
```

And last of all this is  the function that needs to be called using the callee function:

```
WndDyn* Punkt2d::pEditFeldX(WynDyn_callback Dyncallback) {

    return &Edit(pNewStrDataLink(m_x, DLUC_Length, Dyncallback.DecConf), 
                 Dyncallback.AnzSichtChar)
                 .WithSelAllOnFocus(True);
    }
```

My actuall problem is that my compiler is underlining the function `pEditFeldX`
in this line `pEditAll(Dyncallback, pEditFeldX)` in the function pEditpunkt and showing me this Error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error C3867   'Punkt2d::pEditFeldX': non-standard syntax; use '&' to
> create a pointer to member

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
> (active)  E0167   argument of type "WndDyn *(Punkt2d::*)(WynDyn_callback
> Dyncallback)" is incompatible with parameter of type "WndDyn
> *(*)(WynDyn_callback)"

Comment: `return &(temporary)` - that is going to cause Undefined Behavior. The temporary goes out of scope **immediately**, making the `WndDyn*` useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `pEditFeldX` is a member function you can't just call `pEditFeldX(Dyncallback)`. You must call the function on some Punkt2d object, using e.g. `meinPunkt2d.pEditFeldX(Dyncallback)`.

If you write `pEditFeldX(Dyncallback)` *inside the Punkt2d class* then it means `(*this).pEditFeldX(Dyncallback)`. The compiler adds `(*this).` to save some typing.

A function pointer only points to a function. It doesn't point to a function and an object. It points to `pEditFeldX`, not `meinPunkt2d.pEditFeldX`. You must specify the Punkt2d object when you call it.

To remember that a Punkt2d must be specified, a function pointer which points to a member function is declared as this: `WndDyn* (Punkt2d::*func_Call)(WynDyn_callback)` and called as this: `meinPunkt2d.*func_Call(Dyncallback);`

If the function pointer is `&pEditFeldX` then `meinPunkt2d.*func_Call(Dyncallback)` is the same as `meinPunkt2d.pEditFeldX(Dyncallback)`

This doesn't apply to `static` member functions. Static member functions can be used with normal function pointers since no object is required.

---

It is not quite clear what you are trying to do, but if I understand it right, I think that `std::function` would be able to solve your problem `std::function` is able to store *anything* which can be called, including "half of a function call" like you seem to want. `std::bind` can make these "half function calls".

You could use them like this:

```
// in pEditPunkt
pEditAll(Dyncallback, std::bind(&CPunkt2d::pEditFeldX, this, std::placeholders::_1))

// in pEditAll
WndDyn*   pEditAll(WynDyn_callback& Dyncallback, std::function<WndDyn* (WynDyn_callback)> (func_Call) 
  (WynDyn_callback)) {
    return  func_Call(Dyncallback);
}
```

Comment: could you please explain to me what is the different betwenn func_call and pfunc_call. Otherwise i'm a little bit confused. Because the object myPunkt2d that i need to define needs to have the pointer function defined. Could you please give my some more explanation just for this line myPunkt2d.*pfunc_Call(Dyncallback); i'm really thankfull for your help

Comment: @zakaria14 pfunc_Call was a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: @zakaria14 When you call pEditFeldX you have to have a Punkt2d object. You can't just call `pEditFeldX(something)`, it has to be `something.pEditFeldX(something)`. (Unless you call it from the same class. Then `pEditFeldX(something)` stands for `(*this).pEditFeldX(something)`)

Comment: @zakaria14 well, on which Punkt2d object do you want to call the function?

Comment: @zakaria14 The computer cannot call pEditFeldX, unless it knows which Punkt2d should be edited. How is the computer supposed to know which Punkt2d should be edited?

Comment: let's suppose that i'm going to declare an empty Punkt 2d Object in the function pEditAll as follow: *WndDyn* Punkt2d::pEditPunkt( WndInfo& wi, Int32 AnzSichtChar, Bool WithUnit, const K_DecimalsConf& DecConf)
{
 K_WynDyn_callback Dyncallback;
 Dyncallback.AnzSichtChar = AnzSichtChar;
 Dyncallback.WithUnit = WithUnit;
 Dyncallback.DecConf = DecConf;
 Punkt2d *X;
   return &(DlgZeile(wi)
    + pEditAll(Dyncallback, X->pEditFeldX)//pEditFeldX(AnzSichtChar     );

Answer (score 0):

First of all i would like to thanks @user253751 for his patient and great support. i would like to share with you how my code look like now:

```
#include <functional>
// pointer function
WndDyn*   pEditAll(WynDyn_callback& Dyncallback, std::function<WndDyn* 
            (K_WynDyn_callback)>func_Call) {
    return  func_Call(Dyncallback);
}

//the calle
 WndDyn* K_Punkt2d::pEditPunkt( WndInfo& wi, Int32 AnzSichtChar, 
 Bool WithUnit, const DecimalsConf& DecConf)
{
    WynDyn_callback Dyncallback;
    Dyncallback.AnzSichtChar = AnzSichtChar;
    Dyncallback.WithUnit = WithUnit;
    Dyncallback.DecConf = DecConf;
    
   return &(DlgZeile(wi)
                + pEditAll(Dyncallback, 
     std::bind(&Punkt2d::pEditFeldX, this, 
     std::placeholders::_1))//pEditFeldX(AnzSichtChar, WithUnit, 
      DecConf)
                + FntXUnit(2)
                + pEditFeldY(AnzSichtChar, WithUnit, DecConf)
              );
}
```